# HTML Unity PlugIn not working in wiki

Tags: html, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have a wiki at http://toneme.org

I would like to run a unity plug-in on the main page.   as a test, I have a simple unity project, which comprises a .html and a .unity3d binary.   here is the contents of the .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Unity Web Player | thelostcity</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function GetUnity() {
            if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
                return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer");
            }
            return null;
        }
        if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
            unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "thelostcity.unity3d", 1024, 768);

        }
        -->
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #000;
        }
        a:active, a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        p.header {
            font-size: small;
        }
        p.header span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        p.footer {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        div.content {
            margin: auto;
            width: 1024px;
        }
        div.missing {
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            width: 193px;
        }
        div.missing a {
            height: 63px;
            position: relative;
            top: -31px;
        }
        div.missing img {
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        div#unityPlayer {
            cursor: default;
            height: 768px;
            width: 1024px;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="header"><span>Unity Web Player | </span>thelostcity</p>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="unityPlayer">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

now if I double click the .html,  Google Chrome loads it up perfectly.

but if I copy the binary into the wiki's files,  edit the wiki Main Page -> insert HTML widget ->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//
                <!--
                function GetUnity() {
                        if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
                                return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer");
                        }
                        return null;
                }
                if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
                        unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "thelostcity.unity3d", 1024, 768);

                }
                -->
//
</script>
<p class="header"><span>Unity Web Player |</span> thelostcity</p>
<div class="content">
<div id="unityPlayer">
<div class="missing"><a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63"></img></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="footer">« created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com" rel="nofollow">Unity</a> »</p>
```

...it refuses to run:

[image]

What is going on?   why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely the location you're putting the binary. If the binary isn't at http://toneme.org/thelostcity.unity3d then it's not finding it, hence your error.

Comment: This is spot on. The wiki, when I upload a file, stores it in eg "/file/view/thelostcity.unity3d" so I just needed to replace "thelostcity.unity3d" with "/file/view/thelostcity.unity3d"  in the HTML widget. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up, [this page](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/HTML%20code%20to%20load%20Unity%20Web%20Player%20content) details how to write the necessary HTML to display the widget locally,  which is as follows:

```
<html>

<head> </head>


<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    unityObject.embedUnity(
        "unityPlayer", 
        "CS.unity3d", 
        300, 300
    );
-->
</script>

<div id="unityPlayer" />
</body>

</html>
```

therefore I just need to create a widget in my wiki with the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    unityObject.embedUnity(
        "unityPlayer", 
        "/file/view/CS.unity3d", 
        300, 300
    );
-->
</script>

<div id="unityPlayer" />
```